# Aligning symbols underneath each other neatly

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align the equal and greater than signs underneath each other but can't seem to get them aligned properly (see image attached). How can I align them correctly? I have included my lines of code below.

[image]

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E\big[\widehat{V}_i^{j_1...j_i}|X_i^{j_1...j_i}\big] = E\Bigg[max\Bigg\{h_i(X_i^{j_1...j_i}),\frac{1}{b}\sum_{j=1}^{b} \widehat{V}_{i+1}^{j_1...j_ij}\Bigg\}|X_i^{j_1...j_i}\Bigg] \\

\geq max\Bigg\{h_i(X_i^{j_1...j_i}),E\Bigg[\frac{1}{b}\sum_{j=1}^{b} \widehat{V}_{i+1}^{j_1...j_ij}|X_i^{j_1...j_i}\Bigg]\Bigg\} \\ 

= max\Big\{h_i(X_i^{j_1...j_i}),E\big[\widehat{V}_{i+1}^{j_1...j_ij}|X_i^{j_1...j_i}\big]\Big\} \\ 

\geq max\Big\{h_i(X_i^{j_1...j_i}),E\big[V_{i+1}\big(X_{i+1}^{j_1...j_i1}\big)|X_i^{j_1...j_i}\big]\Big\} \\ 

= V_i\big(X_i^{j_1...j_i}\big).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your equation.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Since you're using `aligned`, you should place an `&` just before the relation (`=` or `\geq`); that is the alignment point you are looking for.  The user guide for the `amsmath` package provides clear instructions for this and other math structures.

Comment: If you're not interested in numbering the equation, use `align*`. Also, there's `\max` instead of `max`, together with `, \dots, ` instead of `...`.

Comment: Off-topic: all-blank lines are not legal syntax if the `amsmath` package is loaded (which is the case here, since you're employing an `aligned` environment).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to providing `&` alignments points in five places, you should also (a) write `\max` instead of `\max` and (b) use large `|` symbols (by writing `\bigm\vert` and `\biggm\vert`). Do please replace all instances of `...` with `\dots`. I would also like to suggest that you use upright-E letters to denote the expectations operator. Do write `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`, etc rather than just `\big(` and `\big)`; that way, the spacing around the opening and closing "fence" symbols can be optimized by LaTeX. Last but not least, don't over-size the fence symbols; e.g., don't write `\Biggl[` when `\biggl[` does just as well -- or, arguably, even better!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\E\bigl[\,\widehat{V}_i^{j_1\dots j_i}\bigm\vert X_i^{j_1\dots j_i}\bigr] 
&= \E\biggl[\max\biggl\{h_i(X_i^{j_1\dots j_i}),\frac{1}{b}\sum_{j=1}^{b} 
   \widehat{V}_{i+1}^{j_1\dots j_ij}\biggr\} \biggm\vert X_i^{j_1\dots j_i}\biggr] \\
&\ge \max\biggl\{h_i(X_i^{j_1\dots j_i}),\E\biggl[\frac{1}{b}\sum_{j=1}^{b} 
   \widehat{V}_{i+1}^{j_1\dots j_ij}\biggm\vert X_i^{j_1\dots j_i}\biggr]\biggr\} \\ 
&= \max\bigl\{h_i(X_i^{j_1\dots j_i}),\E\bigl[\,\widehat{V}_{i+1}^{j_1\dots j_ij}
   \bigm\vert X_i^{j_1\dots j_i}\bigr]\bigr\} \\ 
&\ge \max\bigl\{h_i(X_i^{j_1\dots j_i}),
   \E\bigl[\,V_{i+1}\bigl(X_{i+1}^{j_1\dots j_i1}\bigr)
   \bigm\vert X_i^{j_1\dots j_i}\bigr] \bigr\} \\ 
&= V_i\bigl(X_i^{j_1\dots j_i}\bigr)\,.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

you forgot on ampersands ... and `max` is probably operator `\max`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E\big[\widehat{V}_i^{j_1...j_i}|X_i^{j_1...j_i}\big] 
    & = E\Bigg[\max\Bigg\{h_i(X_i^{j_1...j_i}),\frac{1}{b}\sum_{j=1}^{b}
            \widehat{V}_{i+1}^{j_1...j_ij}\Bigg\}|X_i^{j_1...j_i}\Bigg] \\
    & \geq \max\Bigg\{h_i(X_i^{j_1...j_i}),E\Bigg[\frac{1}{b}\sum_{j=1}^{b}
            \widehat{V}_{i+1}^{j_1...j_ij}|X_i^{j_1...j_i}\Bigg]\Bigg\} \\
    & = \max\Big\{h_i(X_i^{j_1...j_i}),E
            \big[\widehat{V}_{i+1}^{j_1...j_ij}|X_i^{j_1...j_i}\big]\Big\} \\
    & \geq \max\Big\{h_i(X_i^{j_1...j_i}),E
            \big[V_{i+1}\big(X_{i+1}^{j_1...j_i1}\big)|X_i^{j_1...j_i}\big]\Big\} \\
    & = V_i\big(X_i^{j_1...j_i}\big).
\end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` and its variants, from `mathtools`: this allows us to declare  the `\E` and `\Set` command which can take an optional argument, chosen in `\big, \Big, \bigg, \Bigg`, which implicitly adds a pair of `\bigl ... \bigr`, &c., around the delimiters. Alternatively, there is a star version, which adds a pair of `\left ... \right`. Furthermore, the vertical line is translated into a `\given` command, which adapts its size to the delimiters size. Note that in the first two lines, I used smaller delimiters, which I thought more convenient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{mathtools}

\providecommand\given{}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\E[1]{\mathrm E}[]{}{%
\renewcommand\given{\nonscript\:\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\mathopen{}}
#1}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Set[1]\{\}{%
\renewcommand\given{\nonscript\:\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\mathopen{}}
#1}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\E[\big]{\widehat{V}_i^{j_1...j_i}\given X_i^{j_1...j_i}} & = \E[\bigg]{\max\Set[\bigg]{\{h_i(X_i^{j_1...j_i}),\frac{1}{b}\sum_{j=1}^{b} \widehat{V}_{i+1}^{j_1...j_ij}}\given X_i^{j_1...j_i}} \\
 & \geq \max\Set[\bigg]{h_i(X_i^{j_1...j_i}), \E[\bigg]{\frac{1}{b}\sum_{j=1}^{b} \widehat{V}_{i+1}^{j_1...j_ij}\given X_i^{j_1...j_i}}} \\
 & = \max\Set[\Big]{h_i(X_i^{j_1...j_i}),\E[\big]{\widehat{V}_{i+1}^{j_1...j_ij}\given X_i^{j_1...j_i}}} \\
 & \geq \max\Set[\Big]{h_i(X_i^{j_1...j_i}),\E[\big]{V_{i+1}\bigl(X_{i+1}^{j_1...j_i1}\bigr)\given X_i^{j_1...j_i}}} \\
 & = V_i\bigl(X_i^{j_1...j_i}\bigr).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]